# How check if wordpress user ID matches with other data tabale ID and then display data according to matched IDs using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Here is what I am trying to acheive on my wordpress site.

I would like to compare 2 data sources from 1 database.
For example when a random wordpress user logs in, I would like PHP to get his user ID and then check if that ID matches with other table's ID and then if they match display content in frontend according to matched ID.

Table 1 is wordpress wp_users and table 2 is a table which has its own id and contains data. Data which table 2 contains is related to wordpress users. Each wordpress has its own data.

I need to display this data in frontend of the website after matching validation is done.

I managed to display data in front end but stuck in comparing two tables.

Here is what I got:

```php
$user = get_userdata($user_id);

$h5p = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT id FROM wp_h5p_results ");

if ($user == $h5p) {
    $total_score = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT score FROM wp_h5p_results ");
    echo "<p>Your Score {$total_score}</p>";
} else {
    echo 'No user with such ID';
}
```

Comment: Overlooking some of the coding errors. Your queries will always return the same results if it doesn't throw an error. You have no where clause. Like `SELECT id FROM wp_h5p_results where id = $user_id`

Comment: As you stated. My problem is that it displays data from table 2 but its always the same as my code doesnt compare user id and display according to match ID. Thats where I need a help

Comment: Any reason  why you can't JOIN the 2 tables in a single query?  I don't use WordPress so I can't help much.

Comment: The reason is because Users have their own table provided by wordress and then we have second table which was created by plugin that I installed

Comment: @ImranYunus! To be honest, there are lots of quirks in your code, and I refrain a little from simply correcting everything. But I have some hints: Check what the `get_var` function does https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_var/ You might rather want to use the `get_results` with a proper query that uses a `WHERE` clause that compares the current user's id with the id stored in H5P's results table. You might want to check H5P's results table that can contain _multiple_ entries with the same user id as the table lists the results for all H5P exercises completed by the user.